# A PHP Error was encountered while seeting up CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to set up my first project in CodeIgniter. I'm following the steps as shown in this page :`http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/everything-you-need-to-get-started-with-codeigniter--net-2634`
When trying to follow the 8th step I have an error.
This is my code:

```html
<?php
    class diploma extends Controller{
        function index()
        {

        
            $this->load->model('diploma_model');
 
            $data['result'] = $this->diploma_model->
           <span class="sql">getData </span>();
          
            $data['page_title'] = "CI Hello World App!";
 
            $this->load->view('diploma_view',$data);
        }
    }
?>
```

This is my error:
[image]

I'm new at CodeIgniter. Can someone explian me why this error occurs? Thanks!

After editing this piece of code

```html
 $data['result'] = $this->diploma_model->
               <span class="sql">getData </span>();
```

like this:

```html
 $data['result'] = $this->diploma_model->
               getData ();
```

This is my error now:
[image]

Comment: you're mixing raw html with php code. that's flat out not possible.

Comment: Don't rely on old tutorials or tutorials for old versions much. Stick with docs rather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors

1. **missing the Model method** to call in Controller
2. **Wrong Model callback**

```
$data['result'] = $this->diploma_model-> # Missing here
```

Example

```
$data['result'] = $this->diploma_model->getData();
```

---

**FYI**

This is wrong

```
$data['result'] = $this->diploma_model->
           <span class="sql">getData </span>(); # span class cannot add to the model callback function
```

this should be

```
$data['result'] = $this->diploma_model->getData();
```

---

**EDIT**

This should be

```
class diploma extends Controller{
```

Change to this

```
class Diploma extends CI_Controller {
```

Comment: I have the getData method there

Comment: @Doe do like this `$data['result'] = $this->diploma_model->getData();`

Comment: @Doe read this https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#loading-a-model

Comment: Ok thanks! Now It says classs Controller not found :/

Comment: check in model there is method call `getData`

Comment: check you model and controller working fine.Now error is in your design pattern

Comment: That should be on one line `$data['result'] = $this->diploma_model->getData();`